# MySQL, Getting True Duplicate Records

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I am trying to sift through a table with thousands of records and I need to get true duplicate rows. By true I mean records where **all the columns** are identical.

I am using something like this for the moment but it obviously only finds duplicates in column_1:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
    WHERE `column_1` IN (
        SELECT `column_1` FROM `table`
        GROUP BY `column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3`
        HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
    )
```

How would I write this to get duplicate rows with all the columns being duplicated excluding IDs? *Without listing ALL the columns in the table?*

Comment: In MySQL, I think you have to list all the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy enough to make your query work for all columns, assuming none have `NULL` values:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `table` t
WHERE (`column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3`) IN (
        SELECT `column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3`
        FROM `table` t2
        GROUP BY `column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3`
        HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
      );
```

If you have `NULL` values, then you want `NULL` safe comparisons:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `table` t JOIN
      (SELECT `column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3`
       FROM `table` t2
       GROUP BY `column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3`
       HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
      ) tt
      ON (NOT tt.column_1 <=> t.column_1) AND
         (NOT tt.column_2 <=> t.column_2) AND
         (NOT tt.column_3 <=> t.column_3);
```

Of course, this is even further from the goal of simplicity.

Why you would need to see *each* duplicate is curious.  Why not just do:

```
        SELECT `column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3`, COUNT(*)
        FROM `table` t2
        GROUP BY `column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3`
        HAVING COUNT(id) > 1
```

In both these cases, though, you need to list out all the columns (at least once).  I don't think there is a way to do this in MySQL otherwise.  Some databases allow you to create a JSON object or XML object for an entire row -- making this possible without listing all the columns.  I cannot think of anything similar in MySQL.

Comment: I've played with this exact idea,,, it is not what I need. Some definitely have null values. I don't have a problem displaying all columns, I have a problem retrieving absolute duplicates. I need to see them because they have to be available for visual overview to the client. You're probably right though,, I'll have to list them at least once :)

Comment: Thank you for this. With some modifications it will work fine